# Polynomial Regression - Unused Arguments

Tags: r, data-modeling, modeling, polynomials

I have a dataset with 269 rows and only two variables (A: measurements, B: the time-point at which it was registered, goes from 1 to 280).

I already removed all NaN values after removing outliers with a Hampel filter.

I am trying to model my data with a Polynomial Regression. I used the following command:

```
model <- lm(A~ poly(B, 15, raw = TRUE), data = data_for_model)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in poly(B, 15, raw = TRUE) : unused arguments (15, raw = TRUE)
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi @philphillis, could you please share your data using `dput(data_for_model)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: check the help page for `poly` (`?poly`), you are supposed to provide the argument name for `degree`, So it would be `poly(B, degree = 15, raw = TRUE)`

Comment: A 15 degree polynomial seems like a Very Bad Idea. Especially a raw rather than an orthogonal polynomial. Perhaps you'd be interested in something like loess or a GAM?

Comment: I can't replicate this error with made-up data.  Can you please post the results of `find("poly")` ?

Comment: @BenBolker, I tried to use ```find("poly")``` , and indeed there was an overlap of functions calling for ```"poly"```.
Solved by implementing: ```model <- lm(A~ stats::poly(B, 15, raw = TRUE), data = data_for_model)```